# Locus length competition math problem

Tags: geometry, contest-math

A  straight  line  passing  through  the  point  $(6,8)$  intersects  the  circle $x^{2}+y^{2}=25$ at two points $P$ and $Q$. Let $M$ be the mid-point of $PQ$. As the slope of the line varies, find the length of the locus of $M$.

I've been trying to solve this for a while, but with no luck.

Comment: What is the length of the locus of $M$?

Comment: HINT. $M$ belongs to the circle of diameter $AO$, where $A=(6,8)$ and $O=(0,0)$.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have an equation for $M$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $A = (6,8)$. Show that $ AM \perp MO$.

**Hint:** Hence conclude that the locus of $M$ is a subset of (the circumference of) the circle with diameter $AO$.

Clearly $M$ is within the circle in the question.

**Hint:** Show that the locus of $M$ is the circumference of the circle with diameter $AO$ that lies within the disc $x^2 + y^2 \leq 25$.

Hence, find the length of the locus of $M$.